# EOF error when using Pool

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing, pool

In my code, I am trying to use multiprocessing to find the max price of each coin given a URL. There are around 1400 coins that I have to get data for, so I implemented Python's multiprocessing Pool. I'm not sure if I am using it correctly, but I followed the example given from this website: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool

max_prices = []

def find_max (url):
    # finds maximum price of a coin
    r = requests.get(url)
    cont = r.json()

    prices = list(map(lambda x: x[1], cont["price_usd"]))
    maxPrice = max(prices)

    return maxPrice


with open("coins.txt", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
coin_slug = [d["slug"] for d in data]
coin_names = [d["name"] for d in data]

urls = []
for item in coin_slug:
    url = "https://graphs2.coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+item+"/"
    urls.append(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(find_max, urls)
```

When I added this part of the code, it gave me an EOF error:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(find_max, urls)
```

Comment: Please post the entire traceback error message.

Comment: It might also help to post some of the content of `coins.txt` so we may reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have unbalanced brackets in the last line. It should be
`print(p.map(find_max, urls))`.